# ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors in StudentsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes **error on assignment [2014, 8, 9] to dob (wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1))**

controller code:

```
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:name, :age, :gender, :dob, :email)
end

def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @student.save
      format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

view code:
    **<%= f.label :dob %>
    <%= f.date_select :dob %>**

Comment: can you show your full form?

Comment: And the full error stack too

Comment: 1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [8, 9, 2014] to dob (wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1))] 
Extracted source (around line #29):
def create
@student = Student.new(student_params)//this line gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that the `date_select` is trying to assign three values (year, month, and day) to `dob` but it doesn't know how to handle it.

It sounds like you may have created your `dob` column as a `string` instead of a `date`.  Can you check your migration to see how `dob` was defined?